# Computing Markov Chain Transition Rates Based On Observed Time

Tags: time-series, probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

## Problem:

I'm working with some data that can be represented with states and transitions, so I would like to model it using Markov chains. Based on the data, I know how much time was spent in each state before transitioning to the next, so I would like to incorporate that time into the transition rates of my Markov chains, but I'm not entirely sure what the best way to do so is.

## Questions:

1. How do we incorporate the observed transition times into our computation of the transition rates?
2. How do we predict future events based on our transition rates?

## Example:

Let's consider an example with three states (**S1**, **S2**, **S3**) and transition probabilities (**P_1**, **P_2**, **P_3**, **P_4**, **P_5**). Assume that we always start in **S1** and end in **S3**.

[image]

Let's define a time step **T** to be 1 second. Now let's say that we observe a transition from **S1** to **S2** at **T=3**. How do we compute the transition rate **P_2** based on this observation?

## Proposed Approach:

Here's one way I think we could compute the transition probabilities. If we start iteratively from **T=0**:

1. At **T=0**, we initialize **P_1 = 1/2** and **P_2 = 1/2**
2. At **T=1**, we know that at **T=0**, we stayed in **S1**, so our probabilities are updated to **P_1 = 2/3** and **P_2 = 1/3**
3. At **T=2**, we know that at **T=1**, we stayed in **S1**, so our probabilities are updated to **P_1 = 3/4** and **P_2 = 1/4**
4. At **T=3**, we observe a transition to **S2**, so our probabilities are updated to **P_1 = 3/5** and **P_2 = 2/5**

So, based on our observations, we know that **P_1 = 3/5** and **P_2 = 2/5**. Assuming this is correct, we should be able to predict future events:

- Probability of transitioning to **S2** from **S1** at **T=1**: $P(S2 | S1, T=1) = P\_2 = 2/5$
- Probability of transitioning to **S2** from **S1** at **T=2**: $P(S2 | S1, T=2) = P(S1 | S1, T=1) \cdot P\_2 = P\_1 \cdot P\_2 = 3/5 \cdot 2/5$
- Probability of transitioning to **S2** from **S1** at **T=3**: $P(S2 | S1, T=3) = P(S1 | S1, T=1) \cdot P(S1 | S1, T=2) \cdot P\_2 = P\_1 \cdot P\_1 \cdot P\_2 = 3/5 \cdot 3/5 \cdot 2/5$

Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something? Any insight and/or resources you could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT]** Ignore **P_5** in the diagram above. We would need to do the same sort of calculations for the transition rates **P_3** and **P_4** for the transition from **S2** to **S3**.

Comment: What roles to $P_3,$ $P_4,$ $P_5,$ and $S_3$ play in your example?

Comment: They're just there to show that we would need to do the same sort of calculations for transitioning from **S2** to **S3**. **P_5** is there by mistake.